# How to produce full author list in the first citation instead of "et al." in *achicago* package?

Tags: bibtex, chicago-style, author-number

I use the `achicago` package and need to produce full list of authors when a source is cited for the first time and then "et al." afterwords. I found that `natbib` has a `longnamesfirst` option that does that. Is this possible with `achicago`?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is unfortunately: No. The `achicago` bibliography style does not provide means to have two different citation texts. It is also incompatible with `natbib`. The `frankenstein` bundle that contains `achicago.bst` is also quite outdated, no longer developed, and quite broken at places.

But there is an easy way out: use the `chicago` bibliography style instead. This is compatible with `natbib`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
  @book{a,
  author = {A. First and B. Second and C. Third and D. Forth and E. Fifth and F. Sixth and G. Seventh},
  title = {My book title},
  year = 2013,
  publisher = {Inhouse}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{a}

\medskip

\cite{a}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]