# Biblatex: How do I truncate in-text author-list after first appearance?

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I am using `biblatex` with `citestyle=authoryear` and `maxnames=5`, along with `\parentcite` in the text.
For papers with 3-5 authors, I would like them to appear with the full list the first time they are cited (as it does now), and with *et al.* the following times.

Example:

First appearance:

```
(Author 1, Author 2, Author 3 and Author 4, 2018)
```

Second appearance:

```
(Author 1 et al., 2018)
```

In [natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115494/how-to-produce-full-author-list-in-the-first-citation-instead-of-et-al-in-ac), this seems to be done with the `longnamesfirst` command, but I haven't found a way to do this biblatex.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48846/35864 help? With `\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{5}}}` and `maxcitenames=2`? If that does not help, please consider adding an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864), so that we can see what you are seeing. It also helps us get started quicker and allows us to test our solution with your general set-up.

Comment: perfect, this does exactly what I wanted, how did I miss this question?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Great! Do we close your question as a duplicate then?

Comment: this question answers the question as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323478/102019

Comment: Yes, definitely a duplicate, sorry about that

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. It is easier to find the duplicate if you already know the answer.